# How can I display a fragment without creating a new one?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an app with a bottom navigation menu and it uses a switch case to change the fragment that is displayed

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch(item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_classes:
                            selectedFragment = new ClassesFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_homework:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeworkFragment();
                            break;
                    }
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
```

However, I have an ArrayList in one of my fragments that holds information from user input that I need to be saved if the app is closed and opened again. With the way I have it now, it just creates a new fragment every time I click on a menu option. How can I make it so it opens/displays a preexisting fragment?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO. android studio is what you're using to develop your app, but your question doesn't involve the IDE at all. best to use `android` and not `android-studio`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store that data outside of the fragment. The fragment can be recreated for a lot of reasons not just by opening/closing the app.

Look up repository pattern and decide where you want (or allowed) to store that data. (Shared preference, room (sqlite) database etc)